# Merge 3 MySql Queries into 1 Query

Tags: mysql

I want to convert below three queries into a single optimized query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS countA FROM table_a
WHERE `date` = '2020-08-17';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS countB FROM table_b
WHERE `date` = '2020-08-17';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS countC FROM table_c
WHERE `date` = '2020-08-17';
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Output]

`UNION ALL` will give the single column as output which I don't need, I want data on 3 separate columns...

Thanks.